Deleting a row from a SQL Server database in ASP.NET MVC
I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm facing a challenge with deleting rows.
Here's the specific scenario: I have two database tables,  AvailableDates and Bookings.
In the UI, users can view available dates. When a user selects a date for deletion, the system should delete the corresponding row from the Bookings table (including the selected date, submitted date, and username).
I've implemented a "Confirm Cancellation" button to initiate the deletion process. Clicking this button results in a 404 error:

This localhost page can't be found. No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44355/Booking/ConfirmCancelBooking

How can I resolve the 404 error and ensure the ConfirmCancelBooking action handles the deletion process correctly?
Models:
public class AvailableDate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
}

Controller:
public class BookingController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public BookingController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult CancelBooking(int bookingId)
    {
        string fullUsername = User.Identity.Name; 

        var booking = _context.Bookings.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == bookingId && b.Username == fullUsername);

        if (booking == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(booking);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ConfirmCancelBooking(int bookingId)
    {
        string fullUsername = User.Identity.Name; 

        var booking = _context.Bookings.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == bookingId 
                                                             && b.Username == fullUsername);

        if (booking == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Bookings.Remove(booking);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

View:
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cancel Booking";
}

<h2>Cancel Booking</h2>

<p>Are you sure you want to cancel your booking for @Model.SelectedDate?</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmCancelBooking", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Cancellation" class="btn btn-danger" />
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Booking")" class="btn btn-secondary">Back to Bookings</a>
}


From the url you posted you don't seem to be passing in the bookingId parameter.

I’m not sure if your example is incomplete but you’ve not supplied your button/form code which could be defaulting to a GET call for which your controller action is not configured for.

Did you try [HttpPost("ConfirmCancelBooking")]? The method now could defined to default path for controller with POST method (without ConfirmCancelBooking in path). Moreover, you might want to use HTTP DELETE method for that [HttpDelete("ConfirmCancelBooking")]

I actually tried it but it didn't work. I've added the view here.

Why don't you just debug and step through to find what is causing the error?

In your ConfirmCancelBooking action your parameter is bookingId, however, because of the following:
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

The hidden input name will be id, meaning the value of bookingId when it hits the controller action will be 0.
So when you perform your database query:
var booking = _context
                .Bookings
                .SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == bookingId 
                    && b.Username == fullUsername);

You'll be looking for a Booking with an Id of 0 which I doubt exists. This will mean var booking is null and therefore your booking null check below it will be true resulting in the 404.
Try changing it to the following:
public IActionResult ConfirmCancelBooking(int id)
{
  // Your code
}

A couple of suggestions.

Provide a short but meaningful response message with your NotFound. For example:

return NotFound($"No booking found for ID {id}");


Make use of ILogger to add some logging output for assisting with debugging.


Thank you, @Peppermintology, for the corrections! They totally worked. Appreciate the suggestions too.

The issue might be coming from the redirect to action that you added,
I changed the type of return and deleted the redirection at the end
Also it's seems like you forgot to give the bookingId
[HttpPost]
public Task<bool> ConfirmCancelBooking([FromBody] int bookingId)
{
   string fullUsername = User.Identity.Name; 

   var booking = _context.Bookings.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == bookingId && b.Username ==        fullUsername);
   if (booking == null)
   {
       return false();
   }

   _context.Bookings.Remove(booking);
   _context.SaveChanges();

   return true;
}

It's the only element that makes you navigate, if it do not solve your problem please update and add the code of the button.
Also you can just do _context.Remove(booking) it works the same as _context.Bookings.Remove(booking)

Hey @Kaiwinta, thanks for the quick tip! My bad for not mentioning the view earlier.
